# Programming the Search button in the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i add a `uisearchbar` and click on it, i get a keyboard with a `Search` button in it. I need to access this button, as in when the user types some string in the `search field` and clicks on search, i need to print a  `NSLog` with the text he entered.

1.) How can i access the `IBAction` of this Search button ?

2.) I also need to close the keyboard when the user clicks on the background, How can i do these programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the UISearchBar delegate, you can "detect" both: the Search Button on SearchBar or the Search Button on Keyboard:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self buttonSearchPressed];
}

-(IBAction)buttonSearchPressed{
    ....
    [yoursearchbar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you implement search bar's delegate method :

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"Search string",[searchBar text]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate).

1)
Implement the method

//this is equivalent to the IBAction you required

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

}
```

2)
Have an outlet for searchbar, say its name, _searchBar.
Implement touchesEnded method as follows.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This is to hide the keyboard.